# Join Postgresql Tables with naming convention

Tags: postgresql

Say you have many Postgresql tables with the same columns and some sort of naming convention.

```
tablename_descriptor:        tablename_anotherdescriptor:      tablename_descriptor3:  
ID         VALUE             ID           VALUE                ID        VALUE
1          val1              1            val4                 1         val7
2          val2              2            val5                 2         val8
3          val3              3            val6                 3         val9
```

Is there a way to join all the tables whose name begins with "tablename"? giving the result

```
tablename:
ID       VALUE
1        val1
2        val2
3        val3
4        val4
5        val5
6        val6
7        val7
8        val8
9        val9
```

Comment: you can write dynamic SQL for that

Comment: I don't think that's how it should worked, perhaps if you have real case of those tables, I can try to know what you are really intend to. Since this example just showed that your schema wasn't so good, beside with those characteristic you can make one table instead of two or more.

Comment: The first schema was given to me, the second schema is the desired one for my program.  Like Roman said, there must be dynamic SQL that accomplishes this. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: What is your expected mapping between each table and the ID column? Your example output show "id 1 = val1", but the source tables also contain "id 1 = val4" and "id 1 = val 17". Are you disregarding the ID column altogether and substituting a new ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some dynamic SQL, the results of which you can execute to get the various tables `UNION ALL`'d together.

```
SELECT string_agg('select row_number() over () as rn,value from ' || tablename,' union all ')
FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE schemaname = 'public'
AND tablename ~* E'tablename\\_descriptor';
```

1). The `row_number()` is there simply to give you an ID (or you could supply a sequence etc).

2). If you are working from the command line, you could execute this query in one `psql` session and pipe it to another to get the results of the generated query.

Eg.

```
psql -U <youruser> -d <yourdb> -qtAc "<the query>" | psql -U <youruser> -d <yourdb>
```